# Can't send data out of executeScript in chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing one chrome extension which can extract all the meta tags of the current tab. I am using ReactJs as the main development environment and I have placed my chrome related code in its `componentWillMount()` method.

```
componentWillMount() {
const code =
    "let metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');" +
    "let newMetas = []" +
    "for (let meta of metas) {" +
    " newMetas.push({name: meta.name, content: meta.content});" +
    "}" +
    "newMetas;";

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
  code: code
}, function (results) {
  console.log(results);  // <=== Here I get 'null' value
  if (!results) {       
    return;
  }      
})}
```

this is my `manifest.json` file

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Northwind",
  "description": "Just a simple all with all northwind employees",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "./img/ic-logo.png",
    "default_popup": "./index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.amazon.com/",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"],
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["http://www.amazon.com/*"],
      "js": ["app.js"]
    }
  ] 
}
```

`app.js` is the build file generated by the react.

I have been reading and searching for this but did not get any clues of why it's not working.

Another issue is that when I put `console.log('done')` in my script, it's not displayed as well so I guess there is some problem with the config as well.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: In the second line of code there is a missing semicolon. It should be `"let newMetas = [];"`. Also remember that `executeScript`'s callback function returns an array, so you'd need to access `results[0]`.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko I added that semicolon after the declaration. But didn't work. Also, I am getting this new error `Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.` Can you please help me with that.?

Comment: Add the host(s) you need to "permissions" section of manifest. Also review [chrome extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview): you cannot place all your current code in a content script, it will not work.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko I updated the manifest file as per your suggestion(also updated in the question) but couldn't get it to work, is there something wrong? I did that by following the docs.

Comment: `chrome.tabs.executeScript` will not run from a content script. You have to call it from a popup or background script. You don't have any background script, according to your manifest. From where is `componentWillMount` called?

Comment: @IvánNokonoko `componentWillMount` will call in the `app.js` which is a build file generated by reactjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` you have to specify host in the *permissions* field of the manifest. 

It is called [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi):

> To insert code into a page, your extension must have cross-origin permissions for the page. It also must be able to use the *chrome.tabs* module. You can get both kinds of permission using the manifest file's permissions field.

Comment: I updated the `persmissions` field in manifest (also updated in the question) but couldn't get it to work. Still getting the same error `Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.` Is there something still wrong with this. I did this by following the docs.

Comment: @AbhilashRathod are you sure that it is "http", not "http**s**"? Try pattern `"https://*.amazon.com/*"`

Comment: Yes @Deliaz that was the issue. I was trying the wrong pattern. Thanks so much for your answer.